# RichTextBlock paragraphs background color

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have a RichTextBlock with a couple of paragraphs. I need some paragraphs to have a background color. I cannot find the Background property on Paragraph or Run. How do I do this? In WPF there is a Block but it does not seem to be present in WinRT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible but it is Possible to insert a InlineUIContainer with a StackPanel with a background.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to get the index for the start of the paragraph and for the end of the paragraph and then use:

```
//Select the line from it's number
int startIndex = richTextBox.GetFirstCharIndexFromLine(lineNumber);
richTextBox.Select(startIndex, length);

//Set the selected text fore and background color
richTextBox.SelectionColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
richTextBox.SelectionBackColor= System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
```

And you could also look at [ScintillaNET](http://scintillanet.codeplex.com/) for a nice Text Editing Control.

Comment: I do not use RichTextBox but RichTextBlock

Comment: So it's not possible, you'll have to switch to RichTextBox..
Unless you create your own class that inherits from RichTextBlock and then codes the whole draw part again.

Comment: RichTextBlock is a sealed class. Also, I'm sure there was probably a good reason for this compromise (though it's causing me a good deal of pain at the moment.)