# Background color part of textbox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, win-universal-app

I've been trying to set a background color to a part of a textblock. Since there is no function to this with in the TextBlock itself I figured I should be adding inlines.

However the inline objects (Run, Span, e.g) have a private background field that gets its value from the parent TextBlock.

I figured I'd try to use an InlineUIContainer. Here is the code I used:

```
Grid grid = new Grid();
grid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
TextBlock block = new TextBlock();
block.Text = temp2;
grid.Children.Add(block);

InlineUIContainer iuic= new InlineUIContainer();
iuic.Child = grid;

Parent_TextBlock.Inlines.Add(iuic);
```

This last line gives an ArgumentException. Is there a way to change a part of a TextBlocks background color? If so, am I on the right track?

Comment: Can't you use `TextBlock.Background` property ?

Comment: In WindowsPhone TextBlock not contains Background property, only in WPF

Comment: I want to change a part of the textblocks background, not it's entire background. Basically I have a long string, and a single word needs to be "highlighted". So using the textblock's background property would not do what I want it to do, in this case

Comment: @f14shm4n I didn't know that, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be following option can helps you.

You can use **RitchTextBox**, since in WindowsPhone RitchTextBox is read only (as an TextBlock).
My quick sample :) :

```
        <RichTextBox>
            <Paragraph>
                Some textSome textSome textSome textSome
                <Span Foreground="#FF0E0E0E">textSome textSome textSome</Span>
                textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome 
                textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome
                <InlineUIContainer> <!-- Look this -->
                    <Border Background="Blue">
                        <TextBlock Text="textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome text"/>
                    </Border>
                </InlineUIContainer>
                textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome 
                textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome textSome
            </Paragraph>
        </RichTextBox>
```

**UPD #1** Do not forget about TextWrapping for Inline TextBlocks

Comment: I'm seeing a RichTextBlock, not a RichTextBox. When I try to use it I get the message: "does not contain a definition for 'inlines'".

Comment: You can read this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602717/richtextblock-paragraphs-background-color) with similar question, but I guess RichTextBlock behaves just like the TextBlock (can't add InlineUIContainer in InlineCollection) (I don't worked yet in WP 8.1 where has been added RitchTextBlock). Based on this, only one option can be used in this case that is RitchTextBox (as I said, this control behaves just like TextBlock, because isReadOnly in Silverlight).